# Javascript and PHP timestamps different, giving different time

Tags: php, javascript

I'm getting different values for timestamp using javascript and PHP when code is executed almost at the same time.

using Javascript Date.getTime(), i get 
    1375228800000

for timestamp while at the same time PHP reports 
    1375233890

as timestamp from a call to time().

The first ten digits are close but the timestamp from javascript has extra 3 digits (000) which I think is causing PHP to return the date as 1996-08-05 17:08:40 instead of 2013-08-31.

I'm running Javascript and PHP on the same machine.

Why is Javascript adding extra digits (000) and how can I solve this problem? Please help.

Comment: Those extra 3 digits are _milliseconds_. Divide by 1000.

Comment: don't forget to consider the timezone. JS is client-side while PHP is server-side. do not assume the client and the server are in the same TZ.

Answer (score 7):

JavaScript measures time in milliseconds, not in seconds.  Just divide by 1,000.

Comment: Yes! worked great. Thanks.